# Smack throws "Exception in thread "Smack Packet Reader (0)" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils.parseDate"

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am trying to create Multi user chat group from App Server(TOMCAT),I have created a XMPP bot in a servlet.

As per my requirement i have to create a Multiuser Chat group from App server(using xmpp bot on app server),and join user from android app.

Creation of Multi user chat group and joining user from Android(using aSmack)works just fine,when i try to do same thing on appServer(TOMCAT),i am getting error,

At first when I try to create MUC i was getting "Can't create a multi user chat (MUC) room with aSmack library for Android: “packet.DefaultPacketExtension cannot be cast to packet.MUCUser”,

When i searched on SO i found [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174040/cant-create-a-multi-user-chat-muc-room-with-asmack-library-for-android-pack) in which @FLOW has mention reson for this error which is

> org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension cannot be cast to
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.MUCUser is usually an indicator that
>   you didn't initialized the static code of aSmack that takes care of
>   registering the Smack providers for the various packet (and packet
>   extension) classes of Smack.
>   For most aSmack versions, simply calling
>
> SmackAndroid.init(Context ctx)
>
> will do the trick.

There is no such method in core Smack package which takes care of registering the Smack providers for the various packet (and packet extension) classes of Smack.

So i have manually configure provide using  configure(ProviderManager pm) method on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174040/cant-create-a-multi-user-chat-muc-room-with-asmack-library-for-android-pack)

Now after configuring provider everything should be working fine but still i am unable to create MUC group

My code is as below

```
    SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(packetReplyTimeout);

    if(service != null)
        config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port, service);
    else
        config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port);

    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();

    System.out.println("Connected: " + connection.isConnected());
    chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
    messageListener = new MyMessageListener();

if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
        configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());
        connection.login(username, password);
    }
   MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "1234567@conference.localhost");

        muc.create("Jonny");

          Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
             Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();

            for (Iterator<FormField> fields = form.getFields(); fields.hasNext();) {
                FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();  
                if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType())
                        && field.getVariable() != null) {
                   // show("field: " + field.getVariable());
                    // Sets the default value as the answer
                    submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
                }
            }

            List<String> owners = new ArrayList<String>();

            owners.add(xmppManager.getXmppConnection().getUser());
            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
            //submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", );
            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
            muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
            muc.join(MucNick);
            muc.sendMessage("hello everybody");
            muc.addMessageListener(
                    new PacketListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                                message = (Message) packet;
                            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                                        .getFrom());
                                System.out.println("andro xmpp client"+ "Text Recieved--" + message.getBody()
                                        + " from " + fromName );
                                //messages.add(fromName + ":");
                                //messages.add(message.getBody());
                                //infobox.append("message arrieved "+" from::"+message.getFrom()+"__"+message.getBody());

                                // Add the incoming message to the list view
                                //Log.i("andro xmpp client","group messages__"+ messages.toString());

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    );
```

here is Stack Trace::

```
Exception in thread "Smack Packet Reader (0)" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils.parseDate(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Date;
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.DelayInformationProvider.parseExtension(DelayInformationProvider.java:45)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.parsePacketExtension(PacketParserUtils.java:768)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.parsePresence(PacketParserUtils.java:248)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:232)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
No response from server.: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.create(MultiUserChat.java:367)
    at com.sentiinel.egovern.testcase1.testing2.createMUC(testing2.java:510)
    at com.sentiinel.egovern.testcase1.testing2.insertRequest(testing2.java:303)
    at com.sentiinel.egovern.testcase1.testing2.doPost(testing2.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.sentiinel.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help with above problem will be really helpful

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no such method in core Smack package which takes care of
>   registering the Smack providers for the various packet (and packet
>   extension) classes of Smack.

Yes there is (although not in smack-core).

> So i have manually configure provide using configure(ProviderManager
>   pm) method on this link

**Never** manually configure the provider (at least not, if you are don't know what you are doing).

> Exception in thread "Smack Packet Reader (0)"
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils.parseDate(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Date;
>       at org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.DelayInformationProvider.parseExtension(DelayInformationProvider.java:45)

You are seeing a `NoSuchmethodError`. For some reason, the `parseDate` method in StringUtils does not exists as excepted by `DelayInformationProvider`. Could it be that you are mixing Smack components of different major versions? Which Smack version do you use?

Comment: i am using smack version 3.2.2

Comment: That version is very old and has severe bugs. I recommend using the latest stable version, which is currently Smack 4.0.4.

Comment: yes after reading you answer i though version i am using must be old or out dated so i started working on 4.0.4 ,i was only using smack V-3.2.2 because i have to implement bosh functionality on app server(TOMCAT) i could examples which are using smack 3.2.2 but now i am able to make smack connection using XMPPBOSHConnection class ,as you said in your answer there is method available for registering the Smack providers for the various packet and you also recommend "Never manually configure the provider",can you give me any example By which i can register Smack Provider for the various packages.

Comment: You only need to register custom providers, everything else will be taken care of by Smack.

Comment: How can i register Custom provider??                              say for Group Chat Invitations "ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());"
like this???

Comment: Read the Smack documentation on custom providers: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html